# Error loading a screen in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

When I try to load a screen it gives an error. It has a Relative Layout and inside there is a Table Layout. The error is about screen inflation so I think somehow that is related.

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#777777"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:text="Choose"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="#000000" >
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/Header1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtProblema"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#FFF000"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Problema"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAbreviatura"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#FFF000"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Abreviatura"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkWorms"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtWorms"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@string/table_bg_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Gusano"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtGU"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="GU"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@string/abrv_bg_color"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkCSBAdult"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCSBAdult"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@string/table_bg_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CSB-Adulto"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCSBA"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CSB-A"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@string/abrv_bg_color"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkCSBLarva"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCSBLarva"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@string/table_bg_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CSB-Larva"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCSBL"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CSB-L"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@string/abrv_bg_color"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkCSFLarva"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCSFLarva"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@string/table_bg_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CSF-Larva"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCSFL"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CSF-L"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@string/abrv_bg_color"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkAves"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAves"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@string/table_bg_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Aves"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAve"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Ave"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@string/abrv_bg_color"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkThrips"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtThrips"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@string/table_bg_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Thrips"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTH"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TH"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@string/abrv_bg_color"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkHongo"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHongo"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@string/table_bg_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hongo"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHG"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="HG"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@string/abrv_bg_color"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkBacteria"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBacteria"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@string/table_bg_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Bacteria/Pudrición"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBac"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Bac"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@string/abrv_bg_color"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkKernelPopping"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtKernelPopping"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@string/table_bg_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Kernel Popping"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtKP"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="KP"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@string/abrv_bg_color"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkNoKernel"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNoKernel"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@string/table_bg_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="No Kernel"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNK"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="NK"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@string/abrv_bg_color"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnNoKernel"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSave"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:onClick="SaveKernelInspection"
    android:text="Save" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my Manifest just in case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.domedroid"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.domedroid.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.domedroid.DomeScreen"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.domedroid.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.domedroid.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.domedroid.PotholderScreen"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.domedroid.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.domedroid.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.domedroid.PlantScreen"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.domedroid.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.domedroid.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.domedroid.DataSelectionScreen"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.domedroid.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.domedroid.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.domedroid.InspectionScreen"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.domedroid.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.domedroid.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.domedroid.KDCScreen"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.domedroid.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.domedroid.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.domedroid.KernelInspectionScreen"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.domedroid.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.domedroid.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

There is no code for these screens other than the usual OnCreate and the onCreateOptionsMenu. Of course, the setContentView is set to that screen. The error is this:

```
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.domedroid/com.example.domedroid.KernelInspectionScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at com.example.domedroid.KernelInspectionScreen.onCreate(KernelInspectionScreen.java:10)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     ... 11 more
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     ... 26 more
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File #0f6f0f from drawable resource ID #0x7f040002
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1970)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3328)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:454)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:449)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     ... 29 more
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: #0f6f0f
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:407)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1962)
02-01 13:20:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(6494):     ... 33 more
```

Thank you for any help!

EDIT: I am adding the code of the class. Like I said, it doesn't have much important code but maybe you guys can see something that I can't.

```
package com.example.domedroid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class KernelInspectionScreen extends MainActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kernel_inspection_screen);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eclipse sometimes falls behind generating resource IDs. If you're using Eclipse, try cleaning your project and rebuilding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it did not work.

Comment: @plasmy is this the same layout file you have shown which is used for `KernelInspectionScreen.java` activity?

Comment: That is correct @PratikSharma

Comment: @plasmy try with the solution I have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think  the problems come from the fact you use a String as a background

> android:background="@string/table_bg_color"

It should be a color object.

Comment: Yes sir this was exactly the problem. I changed all of the colors I had in string to color objects and it worked just fine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As per me and at looking at your logs error is on this line :

```
android:background="@string/table_bg_color"
```

Try to use this line instead at all places :

```
android:background="#0f6f0f"
```

**OR :**

Make XML file saved at res/values/colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="table_bg_color">#0f6f0f</color>
   <color name="translucent_red">#80ff0000</color>
</resources>
```

And then use like this :

```
android:background="@color/table_bg_color"
```

Thanks.